# Is it possible to use properties from Camel's "timer" component to modify an sql select (by timestamp) used for periodic polling?

Tags: java, sql, apache-camel

I would like to use the "timer" component to poll (select from) a database table by a moving date range.

I wondered if it would be possible to (somehow) use the "firedTime" property to do this...

as in using:

```
exchange.getIn().getHeader("firedTime", String.class)
```

...to build and set date range values in the "where" clause of my select statement.

Is it possible(or advisable) to grab the "firedTime" value, perform the necessary date arithmetic, and build the select statement inside of a "Processor".  Then, set a new Exchange header property within the processor with my newly built SQL string, to forward to the route?

kind of like...

```
    from("timer://theTimerName?fixedRate=true&period=10000")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
                    //get "firedTime" property and use to build startTime and endTime values...
                    //build select statement with date range
                    //   e.g., 
                    //   String pollingSql = "select * from myTable where updateTimestamp between '<startTime>' and '<endTime>'"; 
                    //add "pollingSql" to a header property in exchange(?)
                }
            })
            .toD(pollingSql)//(query)                
            .split(body())
            .convertBodyTo(java.lang.String.class, "UTF-8")
```

Been trying this avenue with no success (same value seems to persist and the data range therefore does not advance in time)

Essentially, would like to know whether this is possible.
-Or, whether there is a better, more acceptable approach to polling with an moving date range (or "timebox")

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am a newby - but, this approach appears to do the trick for me.

```
    from("timer://theTimerName?pattern=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss&fixedRate=true&period=10000")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
                    String firedTime = msg.getIn().getHeader("firedTime", String.class);
                    LocalDateTime ldtnow = LocalDateTime.parse(firedTime,formatter2);
                    LocalDateTime sldt = ldtnow.minusSeconds(5); 
                    LocalDateTime eldt = ldtnow.plusSeconds(60); 
                    String pollingQuery = "sql:select * from myTable where updateTimestamp between '" + sldt.format(formatter) + "' and '" + eldt.format(formatter) + "'?dataSource=myDatasourceBean";
                    msg.getIn().setBody(pollingQuery);
                }
            })
            .toD("${body}")   //the constructed sql statement                
            .split(body())
            .convertBodyTo(java.lang.String.class, "UTF-8")
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. In addition, you may use `Exchange.TIMER_FIRED_TIME` instead of "first dTime" to read the header. [Docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html)